Specify security group when creating auto scale group in AWS..C#
.NET 8
I'm creating an auto scale group using the AWS SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/csharp_ec2_code_examples.html) and its working:
  IAmazonAutoScaling _amazonAutoScaling;
  
 var response = await _amazonAutoScaling.CreateAutoScalingGroupAsync(
     new CreateAutoScalingGroupRequest()
     {
         VPCZoneIdentifier = subnetId,
         AutoScalingGroupName = groupName,
         AvailabilityZones = availabilityZones,
         LaunchTemplate =
             new Amazon.AutoScaling.Model.LaunchTemplateSpecification()
             {
                 LaunchTemplateName = lt_name,
                 Version = "$Default"
             },
         MaxSize = groupSize,
         MinSize = groupSize
     });

I notice the security group for the created instance(s) all point to the default security group. I want my instances to point to my custom security group and not the default. I have looked at the objects used to create an auto scale group and I didn't see anything that lets me set the security group. The subnets are not the answer as I only have one VPC and one subnet for each availability zone.
The line "Version=$Default" has nothing to do with security groups. Here's the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/AutoScaling/TLaunchTemplateSpecification.html)
How do I create an auto scale group and point the created instances to a security group other than default?
Thanks

You can specify security groups as part of the Launch Template.  LaunchTemplateSpecification merely refers to a launch template.  You need to change the launch template itself to adjust the security group(s) of the instance(s) it starts.

Ok, I found this, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/examples-launch-templates-aws-cli.html, but IDK how to add this template programmatically.

I found it here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TCreateLaunchTemplateResponse.html. Thanks
